# module_init macro vs init_module function for built-in kernel modules

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I've been trying to do some light kernel development on Android.

I'm a bit confused about how built-in, built using

```make
obj-y += module_name.o
```

kernel modules use the `module_init()` macro vs the `init_module()` function.

I have the two following simple modules, **first** one:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
int init_module(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "This is our first program.");
    return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "End of our first program.");
}
```

And **second** one

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>

static int __init test_module_init(void)
{
    pr_warn("Hello, world\n");

    return 0;
}

module_init(test_module_init);

static void __exit test_module_exit(void)
{
    pr_warn("Goodbye\n");
}

module_exit(test_module_exit);
```

When I compile the kernel with both modules built-in, the second module is the one that shows a message in `dmesg`. However, the first module does not.

However, if compile the first module separately and load the **.ko* file using `insmod ./module_name.ko` the first module does print messages to `dmesg`.

Is this because the `module_init()` macros are needed to use the load the ELF of the kernel modules during boot time? While the `insmod` loads the ELF dynamically from within the **.ko* file so we don't need to 'register' it using `module_init()` macro?

Comment: First module misses the point how to behave when built-in. It's a different story, but you may look into *include/linux/initcall.h* (IIRC) and check what's done there. For the case when it's built as a module I think it's a (very) old way before those macros exists how to create modules. Don't use it with modern kernels.